# Avoiding sans serif characters when using \text in mathmode

Tags: math-mode, sans-serif

I'm writing a Physics dissertation. The body text is in sans serif font. However, I'd like the font to remain serif in math mode. For example, typing `$V_\text{NL}$` in mathmode gives a sans serif subscript "NL" and I'd like it to be serif.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try `\textrm`?

Comment: Do you really have sans serif text and serif math? I can't believe it! `:-)`

Comment: @egreg pop over to the physics site:-) http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/229381/wronskian-of-complex-second-order-linear-differential-equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use `\text` for such a use in any case it is designed to pick up the current text font (so would be italic in a theorem typically) math identifiers should use `\mathrm` or `\mathsf`.  `\mathrm` would be a serif font by default and could be reset to be so if your code to set up sans serif has redefined it.

Comment: Problem solved... \mathrm was what I wanted not \text. Cheers!